# Laravel 5.2: How to save multiple form fields?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form:

```
<label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control">
   </div>
</div>

<input name="project_id" id="task-project_id" type="hidden" value="{{ $project->id }}">
```

And a method to store the two form fields:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required|max:255',
       'project_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    Task::create([
        'project_id' => $request->project_id,
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();;
}
```

But, only the 'name' is saving to the db table.  The Task table has both column names & while I can echo the correct `$request->project_id` back (to test that it passes) the saved `project_id` is always '0'.

Here's the table:

```
mysql> explain tasks;
```

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| project_id | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Checked the create manually also :

```
App\Task::create(['project_id' => 20,'name' =>'testtt']);
```

Output :

```
App\Task {
        name: "testtt",
        updated_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09", 
        created_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09", 
        id: 25
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to add all the code of your action & schema o your table if possible.

Comment: full action code added. working on how to paste explain tasks; from phpmyadmin.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see the `project_id` attribute at all in your returned task object :

```
App\Task {
    name: "testtt",
    updated_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09", 
    created_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09", 
    id: 25
}
```

That mean you're not allowed the `project_id` attribute in your `Task` model in the `$fillable` array, so make sure that your `$fillable` looks like :

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'project_id'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that it can't be an AUTO_INCREMENT because he says that the setted value is 0, and from what I know, the AUTO_INCREMENT columns starts by 1.

Comment: more info added to q

Comment: Try also to create statically the from code or from tinker `Task::create(['project_id' => 20,'name' =>'test]);`

Comment: Task::create(['project_id' => 20,'name' =>'test']); had the same result... 'test' is there, but the project_id is 0.

Comment: and this is weird right???? >>> \App\Task::create(['project_id' => 20,'name' =>'testtt']);
=> App\Task {#652
     name: "testtt",
     updated_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09",
     created_at: "2016-07-29 01:08:09",
     id: 25,
   }

Comment: Make sure that you have allowed the project_id attribute in your model in the $fillable array...

Comment: I think that was the problem? i've updated the OP with the code posted in the previous comments and updated my answer too...

Answer (score 2):

Ahhhhhhhhh

```
    class Task extends Model
    {
      protected $fillable = ['name', 'project_id'];

      public function tasks()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::Class);
      }
    }
```

project_id needed to be added to the $fillable in the Task Model.

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure that:

- The value `$project->id` is setted and higher than 0.
- Variable `$request->project_id` is setted and higher than 0.
- The column `project_id` exists.

Tell me if you encounter any trouble on these 3 points and I'll try to help you, but I really think that by checking these 3 points in your code you'll find the error! Try function `var_dump($var)` and Browser Inspector to check if all variables are set correctly.

Good Luck!

Comment: This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: Instead of trying to save I tested just echoing $request->project_id & it was the correct id from the page /project/9 on which the form is.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

## On that function try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required|max:255',
       'project_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $task = new Task;
    $task->project_id = $request->project_id;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect()->back();;
}
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models